# WooCommerce send new order email to customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have a problem and it sounds stupid, but I'm really stucked.

I need to send "new order" email also to customer. I tried adding function to functions.php file, and it sends email, but doesn't show most of variables. I inserted the same code into sample php file, added as page in wordpress and it works really well. I really don't know what is going on.

Any solutions? Maybe there is more simple way, like adding recipent to "new order"email in woocommerce? I checked class-wc-email-new-order.php file, but I was not able to change anything in there, I don't understand how it works.

[screen: code working on page VS what is visible in received email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSw35.png)

```
      function create_email_body($order_id){

    global $woocommerce;
    if ( !$order_id )
    return;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $body = '';
    $product_list = '';
    $order_item = $order->get_items();

    foreach( $order_item as $product ) {
        $body .= $product['name']; 
    }

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );


$body ='        <div style = "width: 100%; clear: both;  color: #000;">';
$body .='           <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">';

$body .='               <p> Numer zamówienia:<b> '. $order->get_order_number() .'</b>   </p>';
$body .='               <p> Imię i nazwisko:<b> '. $order->billing_first_name . " " . $order->billing_last_name . '</b> </p>';
$body .='               <p> Sposób dostawy: <b>  '. $order->get_shipping_method() .'</b>    </p>';
$body .='               <p> Status zamówienia:<b>   przyjęte</b>    </p>';
$body .='               <p> Adres dostawy: <b> '. $order->shipping_address_1 . " " . $order->shipping_address_2  . ", " . $order->shipping_postcode . " "    . $order->shipping_city . ", " . $order->shipping_state  . $order->shipping_country .'</b> </p>';

$body .='           </div>';
$body .='           <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">';

$body .='               <p> Data zamówienia:<b> '. $order->order_date . '</b>   </p>';
$body .='               <p> Email:  <b><span style = "color: #000 !important"> '. $order->billing_email . '</b> </span></p> ';
$body .='               <p> Metoda płatności: <b>    '. $order->payment_method_title .'</p>';
$body .='               <p> Numer telefonu:<b> '. $order->billing_phone .'</b>  </p>    ';
$body .='           </div>';
$body .='       </div>';
$body .='       <div style = "width: 100%; clear: both; color: #000; margin-top: 30px;">';

$body .=' <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: "Myriad", sans-serif;" border="1">';
$body .=' <thead>';
$body .='   <tr>';
$body .='       <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;" style = "border: none; color: #000;"></th>';
$body .='       <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;" style = "border: none; color: #000;">Produkt</th>';
$body .='       <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;" style = "border: none; color: #000;">Ilość</th>';
$body .='       <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;" style = "border: none; color: #000;">Cena</th>';
$body .='       <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;" style = "border: none; color: #000;">Wartość</th>';
$body .='   </tr>';
$body .=' </thead>';
$body .=' <tbody>';

            $items = $order->get_items();
            foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
            $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
            $item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item, $_product );

            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {

$body .='               <tr class=' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ) .'">';
$body .='                   <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: none; font-family: "Myriad", sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word; color: #000;">';


$body .='                   </td><td style = "border: none; color: #000">';
                        // Product name
$body .=$item['name'];///'                      <p style = "display: inline-block; float: left">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item['name'], $item, false );
                        if ( ! empty( $item_meta->meta ) ) {
$body .=                             nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true, '_', "\n" ) );
                        }
$body .=                        "</p>";

$body .=                    '</td>';

$body .='                   <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: none; font-family: "Myriad", sans-serif; color: #000">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item['qty'], $item ) .'</td>';
$body .='                   <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: none; font-family: "Myriad", sans-serif; color: #000">' . $_product->get_price();
$body .='                   </td>';
$body .='                   <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: none; font-family: "Myriad", sans-serif; color: #000">' . $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item );
$body .='               </td></tr>';

            }
        endforeach; 

$body .='               </tbody>';
$body .='               <tfoot><td style = "border: none;"></td><td style = "border: none;"></td><td style = "border: none; color: #000;"></td>';
$body .='                   <td style = "border: none; color: #000;">';
$body .='                       <p> Wartość produktów </p> ';
$body .='                       <p> Cena wysyłki </p>';
$body .='                       <p> Do zapłaty </p>';
$body .='                   </td>';
$body .='                   <td style = "border: none; color: #000;">';
$body .='                       <p>' . number_format((float)$order->get_subtotal(), 2, '.', '')  . " zł" . '</p>';
$body .='                       <p>' . number_format((float)$order->get_total_shipping(), 2, '.', '') . " zł" . '</p>';
$body .='                       <p>' . $order->get_formatted_order_total(). '</p>';
$body .='                   </td>';
$body .='               </tfoot>';
$body .='           </table>';
$body .='       </div>';

$body .= file_get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/woocommerce/emails/customer-on-hold.order.php');

return $body;
    } 

    function send_email_also_to_customer($order_id){

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$to_email = $order->billing_email;
$headers = 'Od: AB.com <a@b.com>' . "\r\n";
$mailer = WC()->mailer();
$subject = 'Potwierdzenie przyjęcia zamówienia numer # ' . $order_id;
$body = create_email_body($order_id);
$mailer->send( $to_email, $subject, $mailer->wrap_message( $subject, $body), '', '' );
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_email_also_to_customer');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to do all these stuff again for sending multiple emails. You can simply add recipient to "New Order" email(with customer's email). Here is the code you can try:

```
<?php
/**
 * Add another email recipient for admin New Order emails if a shippable product is ordered
 *
 * @param string $recipient a comma-separated string of email recipients (will turn into an array after this filter!)
 * @param \WC_Order $order the order object for which the email is sent
 * @return string $recipient the updated list of email recipients
 */
function sv_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    // Bail on WC settings pages since the order object isn't yet set yet
    // Not sure why this is even a thing, but shikata ga nai
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ( 'wc-settings' === $page ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }

    // just in case
    if ( ! $order instanceof WC_Order ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // check if a shipped product is in the order   
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

        // add our extra recipient if there's a shipped product - commas needed!
        // we can bail if we've found one, no need to add the recipient more than once
        if ( $product && $product->needs_shipping() ) {
            $recipient .= ', warehouse-manager@example.com';
            return $recipient;
        }
    }

    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'sv_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I changed line $recipient .= ', warehouse-manager@example.com'; to $recipient .= ', ' . $order->billing_email; and now new order email is being sent to customer. That was my point. Thanks again, cheers!

Comment: is which file I need to change it?

Comment: i have woo commerce 8.5.x and it worked for me, just add space after comma. $recipient .= "," . $order->get_billing_email();

Answer (score 4):

WRONG :

```
$recipient .= ', ' . $order->billing_email
```

CORRECT:

```
$recipient .= "," . $order->get_billing_email();
```

I tested and debug this for a whole day.

Answer (score 4):

> **Update 2023** - For WooCommerce 3+ *(Still works on WooCommerce 8.2)*

The accepted answer **code is outdated since Woocommerce 3**, with some errors in the code.

- [`get_product_from_item()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order.html#313-326) method **is deprecated and replaced** by `$item->get_product()`.
- The Customer email is missing
- There is unnecessary code (removed and replaced).

Here is a similar **up to date** and clean version:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'custom_new_order_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function custom_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    // Avoiding backend displayed error in Woocommerce email settings for undefined $order
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) 
        return $recipient;

    // Check order items for a shipped product is in the order   
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product(); // Get WC_Product instance Object

        // When a product needs shipping we add the customer email to email recipients
        if ( $product->needs_shipping() ) {
            return $recipient . ',' . $order->get_billing_email();
        }
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: For WooCommerce 4+ this doesnt seem to work anymore. Do you know why?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec any chance to look at this for woocommerce latest version?

Comment: @pablorenato Just tested that now on latest WooCommerce version (8.2) and it works as intended for New Order notification, adding the customer billing email to recipients when there is a shippable product in the order.

Comment: ahhh I see. we are selling only virtual products. is it possible to include customer in email for virtuals? but to clarify, what is the purpose of "new order" email? it seems woocommerce automatically puts the status into another status after order such as processing. Is that correct? (I'm referring to your other question comment reply). 

All we want is that a customer always receives a notification. Currently I see they get the notification when order goes to processing which appears immediately after payment.

Comment: So you don't need anything as there are email notifications to customer billing email for "on-hold", "processing" and "completed" order statuses.