# How to send a WooCommerce new order email to customer also?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email, woocommerce

By default the recipient is Admin but I want it send it to the customers email also. I saw [WooCommerce send new order email to customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853640/woocommerce-send-new-order-email-to-customer) but it is not specifying where to put the code mentioned. I am a complete noob in WooCommerce so a detailed explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By default WooCommerce sends order mail to customer as well.try by placing an order with your (non-admin) email ID, and you will recive the mail. and one more thing you need to add that code in you active theme `functions.php` file

Comment: @Raunak Oh alright, I was placing orders using my admin Email - ID so I was not receiving emails. 
I checked my active theme folder for functions.php file and I got 4 results  - 

1) shopisle\wp-content\themes\shop-isle\inc\woocommerce\functio‌​ns.php
 
2) shopisle\wp-content\themes\shop-isle\inc\customizer\function‌​s.php

3) shopisle\wp-content\themes\shop-isle\inc\customizer\customiz‌​er-repeater\function‌​s.php 

4) shopisle\functions.php 

Which one do I need to edit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default WooCommerce sends order mail to customer as well.

Try by placing an order with your (non-admin) email ID, provided your theme or any plugin restricting it.

Secondly you need to add that code in your active theme `functions.php` file.
i.e.,

> /wp-content/themes/my_active_theme/functions.php

or you can also add that code in any of the active plugin PHP file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Placed order using non admin email, it worked. 
Thanks!

Comment: Not really. If you look in the emails section you will see the New order e-mail is only sent to the admin.

Comment: @RicardoMartins: I am not sure about the recent changes in WooCommerce, but back then if u placed an order then a mail use to get triggered to the customer as well.

Comment: I've tested with the newest version available using mailtrap.. only admin gets the email, and it will need to be implemented by the payment plugin. =/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the admin email-adress for testing. Just use another email adress.

Ensure that your hosting provider allows for sending emails.

No need to patch any WooCommerce code.