# Where to add a hooked function code snippet for Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I  actually have same case than
*"[WooCommerce send new order email to customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853640/woocommerce-send-new-order-email-to-customer)"* thread and tryied to apply the provided answer, but I am confuses about the location where I have to put these code.

**It is over:** *wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php*? or 
*wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/plain/admin-new-order.php*?

Both of them didn't work, is necessary to create new file? and from where it must be called?

I'll appreciate some help that guides me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, since "emails" folder doesn't exist on my "wp-content/themes/flatsome/wooCommerce".
I'll created and put the file into it, but these bring some issues on my checkout page; about  de step "checkout details" does't no update to "order complete" and   the order  certally is generated

Comment: for now it uptade to "order complete" but still didn't  do nothing (the added script)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the code snippet (from the accepted answer code) to your function.php file located in your active child theme (or active theme).

But the accepted answer code **is outdated since Woocommerce 3** and with some errors as for example `get_product_from_item()` method **is deprecated and replaced**.

> I have added a [**new up to date clean answer** there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853640/woocommerce-send-new-order-email-to-customer/55106343#55106343)

Just for info, you **don't need** to [override any Woocommerce **template**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Got it, I suppose,  the fuction is calling from "wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php" with something like this  "do_action (sv_conditional_email_recipient',  $recipient, $order );" , Rigth? ... but.. nothing.., still no work?

Comment: @WilsonRivas No templates overrides are required… Sorry but it seem that you have overwrite default woocommerce template as `do_action (sv_conditional_email_recipient', $recipient, $order );` doesn't exist on default woocommerce templates, **so you should reinstall Woocommerce plugin**. Now as explained before, you just need to add [**this code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853640/woocommerce-send-new-order-email-to-customer/55106343#55106343) inside your active theme's function.php file.

Comment: hello. I track the message and it possible the isssue is on server, I'll contact them.